# Dropdown in Bootstrap menu not working

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I suspect that I'm not correctly implementing the javascript bootstrap file, since the dropdown menu isn't working. Currently, I have bootstrap saved to my project folder. 
I looked at other working example code (even tried copying and pasting it as a test) and the menu just won't drop down.

Here's my code

```
<head>
  <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "index.css">
  <link href = "bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel = "stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Plethora</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> <img id = "menu" src="nav-icon.png"> </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li><a href="#">Manage Interests </a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Account Settings </a></li>
           <li><a href="#"></a>Email Settings </li>
         </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>`
```

Comment: Is the folder "bootstrap-3.3.6-dist" in the current folder for this html page?  That path is relative to this page not your site so unless this page is your homepage there are likely pathing issues.

Answer (score 0):

The markup works ok. Check your browser console for any 404s when retrieving either the CSS or JS, or get them from a CDN.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
...
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Also, you are missing JQuery from the example code you've posted, this should go before the bootstrap JavaScript.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Example of console**, Firebug in FireFox, check for your script files 404ing in here:

[image]

**Full Working Example**, using CDNs:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Plethora</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> <img id = "menu" src="nav-icon.png"> </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li><a href="#">Manage Interests </a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Account Settings </a></li>
           <li><a href="#"></a>Email Settings </li>
         </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

<sub>([runnable JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmq6dvvw/), note the **3** external resources (Bootstrap CSS and JS and JQuery)</sub>

The only thing not in the above, is your site CSS, so it may be worth trying without that on the off chance something there is interfering, if all else fails.

Answer (score 0):

You're using relative paths for your CSS and JS files instead of absolute.

For example, `bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.css` is relative to whatever page you're on, so if you're on `example.com/ice/cream`, the page is actually trying to load `example.com/ice/cream/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.css` for your CSS file.  If you use `/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.css` for your CSS, it will always load from `example.com/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.css` regardless of what page you're on.

Switch out the relative paths you have for all your CSS and JS, and you should be good be to.

EDIT: As another poster pointed out, you also don't appear to have jQuery on the page, which is required for most Bootstrap functionality to work.